# Select MAX and MIN value of the last 7 records inserted

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I need to select the MAX and the MIN value of the last 8 records inserted for a specific device.
I have a table named **letture** with this structure:

id, id_dispositivo, id_utenza, id_impianto, id_lettura, data, valore

on this table I made a query to extract the last 8 records for id_dispositivo = 1

```
SELECT valore FROM `letture` WHERE id_dispositivo = 1 ORDER BY id_lettura DESC LIMIT 0,8
```

On the result of this query I need to catch the MAX and the MIN value

Comment: Do you want an SQL query for this or do you need to do this with php after you have got the result and saved it to a string? Getting it through query would be better i guess as would require less data management.

Comment: Only the SQL, maybe the PHP later, for now i'm struggling with the sql query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a subquery:

```
SELECT MIN(valore), MAX(valore)
FROM (SELECT valore
      FROM `letture`
      WHERE id_dispositivo = 1
      ORDER BY id_lettura DESC
      LIMIT 8
     ) last8;
```

Comment: last8 is the name of the temporary table?

Comment: @LucaScalvi . . . `last8` is the alias the subquery and is required in MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a subselect:

```
SELECT MIN(valore), MAX(valore) FROM (
  SELECT valore 
  FROM `letture` 
  WHERE id_dispositivo = 1 ORDER BY id_lettura DESC LIMIT 0,8
) T1;
```

Comment: T1 is the name of the temporary table? You answer is correct but I flagged the other because he answered first. Thank You

Comment: `T1` is the alias: each subselect has to have an alias.

Answer (score 0):

---for sql server 2008

```
Create Table Testing(TestID Integer Primary Key,Price Float);
Insert Into Testing Values (1,12.00);
Insert Into Testing Values (2,15.00);
Insert Into Testing Values (3,20.00);
Insert Into Testing Values (4,13.00);
Insert Into Testing Values (5,11.00);
Insert Into Testing Values (6,12.00);
Insert Into Testing Values (7,17.00);
Insert Into Testing Values (8,18.00);
Insert Into Testing Values (9,19.00);
Insert Into Testing Values (10,22.00);

Create Function dbo.GetMinID(@MaxId Integer,@NoOfRows Integer) Returns Integer
as 
Begin
    Declare @MinMax Integer
    IF @NoOfRows > 1  
    Set @MinMax=dbo.GetMinID((Select MAX(TestID) From Testing where TestID <@MaxId),@NoOfRows-1)
    else 
    Set @MinMax=(Select MAX(TestID) From Testing where TestID < @MaxId);                
    Return @MinMax;
End 

Select R.TestID,dbo.GetMinID(R.TestID,8) as MinMax From (Select MAX(TestID) TestID
From Testing) R
```